# Serialisation interface

Tags: java, serialization

Is this possible in Java ?

> public interface Document implements Serializable{ // a lot of method
>   }

Comment: `implements` and `extends` issues are basic of `Java` language, very simple  and short web page explains it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to extend it. "`implements`" is only allowed for classes, which implement an interface.

```
public interface Document extends Serializable { // a lot of method }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to use `extends`:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public interface Document extends Serializable {     
 // a lot of methods
}
```

Comment: Sure, no problem! Remember to mark an answer as the correct one :)

Answer (score 1):

Serializable is a class so you can only extend it not implement it.

```
public interface Document implements Serializable{ // a lot of method }
```

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces **extend** other interfaces and do not **implement** them.

So your code should read:

```
public interface Document extends Serializable { // a lot of method }
```